# Implementing OpenID with Apache Superset. AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, apache-superset

I am trying to implement OpenID in Apache Superset. I am using Broadcom CA-SSO as my provider. I found a similar post in Stack Overflow where someone implemented with Keycloak ([Using KeyCloak(OpenID Connect) with Apache SuperSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010314/using-keycloakopenid-connect-with-apache-superset))
I found the post helpful in my implementation. I have followed the similar approach.

I have been able to authenticate my user with CA-SSO. However, when the browser reaches the callback route, superset is throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, 
in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, 
in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, 
in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 
39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, 
in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, 
in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, 
in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 
39, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, 
in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, 
in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/app/superset/custom_security.py", line 34, in login
return handle_login()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", 
line 487, in decorated
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/superset/custom_security.py", line 31, in handle_login
login_user(user, remember=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", 
line 158, in login_user
if not force and not user.is_active:
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'is_active'
```

Here is my implementation:

client_secrets.json

```
{
    "web": {
        "issuer": "https://<SSO DOMAIN>",
        "auth_uri": "https://<SSO DOMAIN>/authorize",
        "client_id": "<CLIENT ID>",
        "client_secret": "<CLIENT SECRET>",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "https://<YOUR DOMAIN>/oidc_callback"
        ],
        "userinfo_uri": "https://<SSO DOMAIN>/userinfo",
        "token_uri": "https://<SSO DOMAIN>/token",
        "token_introspection_uri": "https://<SSO DOMAIN>/introspect"
    }
}
```

security.py

```
from flask import redirect, request
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import AuthOIDView
from flask_login import login_user
from urllib.parse import quote
from flask_appbuilder.views import ModelView, SimpleFormView, expose
import logging

class AuthOIDCView(AuthOIDView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self, flag=True):
        sm = self.appbuilder.sm
        oidc = sm.oid

        @self.appbuilder.sm.oid.require_login
        def handle_login(): 
            user = sm.auth_user_oid(oidc.user_getfield('email'))

            if user is None:
                info = oidc.user_getinfo(['preferred_username', 'given_name', 'family_name', 'email'])
                user = sm.add_user(info.get('preferred_username'), info.get('given_name'), info.get('family_name'), info.get('email'), sm.find_role('Gamma')) 

            login_user(user, remember=False)
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)  

        return handle_login()  

    @expose('/logout/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def logout(self):

        oidc = self.appbuilder.sm.oid

        oidc.logout()
        super(AuthOIDCView, self).logout()        
        redirect_url = request.url_root.strip('/') + self.appbuilder.get_url_for_login

        return redirect(oidc.client_secrets.get('issuer') + '/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=' + quote(redirect_url))

class OIDCSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authoidview = AuthOIDCView
    def __init__(self,appbuilder):
        super(OIDCSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
        if self.auth_type == AUTH_OID:
            self.oid = OpenIDConnect(self.appbuilder.get_app)
```

In superset/config.py

```
from security import OIDCSecurityManager
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OID
OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS = <path_to_configuration_file>
OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE = False
OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL = False
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Gamma'
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = OIDCSecurityManager
OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI = 'https://<YOUR DOMAIN>/oidc_callback'
```

I am using `flask-oidc`. I am using the default callback `/oidc_callback`. When superset is redirected to `/authorize` endpoint, the redirect_uri was not picked up correctly. It was picking up localhost rather than the domain name, hence I had to use `OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI` flag. It seemed to have fixed that.

Also, I am using Nginx reverse-proxy

Also one weird thing that I noticed. I decoded the `state` query parameter from the `/authorize` Url. It is an object with key `csrf_token` and `destination`. I then decoded the `destination`. It contains the algorithm value and my login route. However, the login URL had localhost (`http://127.0.0.1:8088/login/`) rather then `https://<YOUR DOMAIN>/login`. Is this correct?

I am using superset docker to run the app. I'm new to python-flask.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this, I saw the following additional log before the stacktrace:

```
ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:Error adding new user to database. (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: ab_user.first_name
```

So I updated the `add_user()` call to set an empty (i.e. non-null) first and last name, and it worked after that.

```py
user = sm.add_user(
                    username=info.get("sub"),
                    first_name=info.get("first") if info.get("first") is not None else "",
                    last_name=info.get("last") if info.get("last") is not None else "",
                    email=info.get("email") if info.get("last") is not None else "",
                    role=[security_manager.find_role(role) for role in roles],
                )
```