# Superset with Keycloak - Logged out users are not redirected to login

Tags: python, flask, keycloak, apache-superset

I am trying to implement Superset using Keycloak for authentication.  Following the post here: [Using KeyCloak(OpenID Connect) with Apache SuperSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010314/using-keycloakopenid-connect-with-apache-superset), the login part works fine.

I also have a timeout set on the session (security requirement) using the Superset Docs: https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset#flask-app-configuration-hook

The part that doesn't work, when a user is logged out, they are not redirected to the login page.  It's just a bunch of errors thrown on the screen, and the user can't see anything.  Anyone have a hint as to how I get the user redirected to the login page?

Worth noting, the whole thing is behind an nginx reverse proxy.

Here's the full superset_config.py, in case it's helpful...

````
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import AuthOIDView
from flask_login import login_user
from urllib.parse import quote
from flask_appbuilder.views import ModelView, SimpleFormView, expose
import logging

class AuthOIDCView(AuthOIDView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self, flag=True):
        sm = self.appbuilder.sm
        oidc = sm.oid

        @self.appbuilder.sm.oid.require_login
        def handle_login(): 
            user = sm.auth_user_oid(oidc.user_getfield('email'))

            if user is None:
                info = oidc.user_getinfo(['preferred_username', 'given_name', 'family_name', 'email'])
                user = sm.add_user(info.get('preferred_username'), info.get('given_name'), info.get('family_name'), info.get('email'), sm.find_role('Gamma')) 

            login_user(user, remember=False)
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)  

        return handle_login()  

    @expose('/logout/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def logout(self):

        oidc = self.appbuilder.sm.oid

        oidc.logout()
        super(AuthOIDCView, self).logout()        
        redirect_url = request.url_root.strip('/') + self.appbuilder.get_url_for_login

        return redirect(oidc.client_secrets.get('issuer') + '/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=' + quote(redirect_url))

class OIDCSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    authoidview = AuthOIDCView
    def __init__(self,appbuilder):
        super(OIDCSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
        if self.auth_type == AUTH_OID:
            self.oid = OpenIDConnect(self.appbuilder.get_app)


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'a sting'

MENU_HIDE_USER_INFO = True
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "ROW_LEVEL_SECURITY": True,
    "DASHBOARD_RBAC": True,
}

ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
PROXY_FIX_CONFIG = {"x_for": 1, "x_proto": 0, "x_host": 1, "x_port": 0, "x_prefix": 0}

class ReverseProxied(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        script_name = environ.get('HTTP_X_SCRIPT_NAME', '')
       # print(environ)
        if script_name:
            environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = script_name
            path_info = environ['PATH_INFO']
            if path_info.startswith(script_name):
                environ['PATH_INFO'] = path_info[len(script_name):]

        scheme = environ.get('HTTP_X_SCHEME', '')
        print(scheme)
        if scheme:
            environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = scheme
        return self.app(environ, start_response)


ADDITIONAL_MIDDLEWARE = [ReverseProxied, ]


def role_mapper(role_list):
   # not exposing our roles    


# Auth Settings
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OID
OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS = '/a/path' #real config contains correct path
OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE = False
OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL = False
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Gamma'
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = OIDCSecurityManager


# Webserver Setting
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PROTOCOL = "http"
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_PORT = 8088

# Flask Application Builder Settings
SILENCE_FAB = False
FAB_ADD_SECURITY_VIEWS = True
FAB_ADD_SECURITY_PERMISSION_VIEW = True
FAB_ADD_SECURITY_VIEW_MENU_VIEW = True
FAB_ADD_SECURITY_PERMISSION_VIEWS_VIEW = True


# Session Timeout
from flask import session
from flask import Flask
from datetime import timedelta

def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True

# Set up max age of session to 1 minute for testing
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(minutes=1)
def FLASK_APP_MUTATOR(app: Flask) -> None:
    app.before_request_funcs.setdefault(None, []).append(make_session_permanent)```
````

Answer (score 1):

According to the official superset documentation you can configure your own authentication method (Custom OAuth2 Configuration) https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset/ . Also, in this link you can find the specific parameters for keycloak (https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/security.html). Don't forget to create the additional files as per the instructions. After that, for the logout problem, I solved it by overriding the logout function to this in the custom_sso_security_manager.py:

```
class CustomSsoAuthOAuthView(AuthOAuthView):
@expose("/logout/")
def logout(self):
   
    keycloak_logout_url = "smth/logout"
    logout_redirect_url = 'superset_login_page/login/'
    client_id = ''
    self.appbuilder.app.config["LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL"] = ("{0}?client_id={1}&post_logout_redirect_uri={2}".format(
        keycloak_logout_url,
        client_id,
        logout_redirect_url,   
        
    ))
    logging.debug("LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL: %s", self.appbuilder.app.config.get("LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL"))
    return super().logout()
```

and finally i added `authoauthview = CustomSsoAuthOAuthView` to the CustomSsoSecurityManager class

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue, when user is trying to login again after logout once its throwing 502 error.

I think it's because when a user logs out only from superset, they are getting logged out of it, but in keykloak, their status is kept as logged in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30933850)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.